# On Python, How to open multiple command windows simultaneously (in cascade)

Tags: python, windows, cmd, command, instance

I intend to monitor connectivity (by ping ) 3 devices into the net. So far I tried the follow scripts but in some,  the commands run in a single windows
import os
import multiprocessing

```
def  xxx():
    while True:
        os.system('cmd /c "ping 192.168.1.254  -t "  ')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(3 ):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=xxx)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
# _______________________________________________________

import threading
import os
def xxx():
    os.system('cmd /c "ping  192.168.1.254  -t "  ')
def yyy():
    os.system('cmd /c "ping  127.1.1.0  -t "  ')
def main():
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=xxx)   
    client_thread = threading.Thread(target=yyy)
    server_thread.start()
    client_thread.start()
#__________________________________________________
import os
import multiprocessing
def xxx():
  os.system(   'cmd /c "ping  192.168.1.254  -t  "  ')
def yyy():
  os.system('cmd /c "ping  127.1.1.0  -t "')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=xxx)   
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start() 
    q = multiprocessing.Process(target=yyy)  
    jobs.append(q)  
    q.start()
```

Comment: You haven't started what the problem you're encountering is

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just run another Python script where you put your ping method or other from your main script with

```
subprocess.call('python ping_script.py', shell=True)
```

But if you want to have some visual on your processes I would recommend you to use Jupyter notebooks